# Set custom dialog height and width

Tags: android, xml, dialog

I am making a custom dialog of which I want height and width to be default fit to all screen sizes.

But it is not happening so.
The dialog is appearing very small though.
THis is the XML for the dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#D24379"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yesButton"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/yes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="@string/no" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my dialog class

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
            android.view.View.OnClickListener {

        public Activity c;
        public Dialog d;
        public Button yes, no;
        public TextView content;

        public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
            super(a);
            this.c = a;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
            no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noButton);
            content=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_dia);
            yes.setOnClickListener(this);
            no.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.yesButton:

                break;
            case R.id.noButton:
                dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            dismiss();
        }
      }
```

How do I set the height and width to appear a default size such that it appears perfect on all screen size.

I am a getting a very small dialog.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not Dialog Class use, Try This Class :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


                     ShowDialog();

        }

        private void ShowDialog() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

                dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

                Button yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
                yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                Button no = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.noButton);
                no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent i = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                  TextView content =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_dia);



                dialog.show();
            }
}
```

Comment: `dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);` needs setting AFTER `dialog.show()`

Answer (score 5):

In class extending  Dialog    :

```
public MyPopUp(MainActivity activity, String sPrm) {
    super(activity);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
    LinearLayout bedLcl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bed);
    TextView textLcl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
    textLcl.setText(sPrm);
    setOnCancelListener(this);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int widthLcl = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels*0.9f);
    int heightLcl = (int) (displayMetrics.heightPixels*0.9f);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsLcl = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) 
    bedLcl.getLayoutParams();
    paramsLcl.width = widthLcl;
    paramsLcl.height =heightLcl ;
    paramsLcl.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    show();
    Window window = getWindow();
    bedLcl .setLayoutParams(paramsLcl);
    window .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));}
```

[image]

Correctly for all screens.

Answer (score 4):

Put `this.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`
 in your custom dialog's `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `android:gravity="center"` to your LinearLayout and then set a minimum height on the LinearLayout as well, e.g. `android:minHeight="120dp"`. You can then test your layout on various devices and tweak it until you get something that works on all screen sizes:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="120dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#D24379"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your lay put try now

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#D24379"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:text="Are you good?"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yesButton"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:text="YES" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/noButton"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:text="NO" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should state what exactly you changed.